# How could we continue to get a contradiction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega$ a bounded space. Using the maximum principle I have to show that the following problem has an unique solution.

$$-\Delta u(x)=f(x), x \in \Omega \\ u(x)=g(x), x \in \partial{\Omega}$$

I have done the following:

Let $u_1$, $u_2$ be two different solutions. Then $w=u_1-u_2$ solves the problem $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
-\Delta w(x)=0, x \in \Omega \\ 
w(x)=0, x \in \partial{\Omega}
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta w(x)=0, x \in \Omega \\ 
w(x)=0, x \in \partial{\Omega}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Can we apply the maximum principle because we have that $\Delta w=0 \geq 0$ ??

From the maximum principle we have that $\max_{\Omega} w=\max_{\partial{\Omega}}w$.

So, we have that $w(x) \leq \max_{\partial{\Omega}}w$.

We will show that $\max_{\partial{\Omega}}w\leq 0$.

We suppose that this is not true, this means that $\exists x_0 \in \partial{\Omega}$: $\max_{\partial{\Omega}}w=w(x_0)>0$.

Is this correct so far??

How could we continue to get a contradiction??

Comment: Apply maximum principle to both $w$ and $-w$. From $\Delta w \geq 0$ maximum $w$ is achieved on the boundary. From $\Delta w \leq 0$ also is minimum. So $\min w = \max w = 0$

Comment: Since we have that $\Delta w=0$ we take the cases $\Delta w\geq 0$ and $\Delta w \leq 0$, or have I understood it wrong?? @uranix

Comment: Being zero is a special case of being "less than zero" as well as being "greater than zero". That are not cases we test, $w$ satisfies both of them.

Comment: But when $\Delta w\leq 0$ do we not use the minimum principle?? @uranix

Comment: You could see it as using the maximum principle on $w$ and $-w$, or using the maximum principle and the minimum principle simultaneously on $w$. They are equivalent methods.

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out we have
\begin{align*}
-\Delta w & = 0 \text{ in }\Omega \\
w & = 0 \text{ on }\partial\Omega
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
-\Delta (-w) & = 0\text{ in }\Omega \\
-w & = 0\text{ on }\partial\Omega
\end{align*}
Thus we can use the maximum principle for $w$ and $-w$, yielding $\max_\Omega w = \max_{\partial\Omega} w =0$ and $\max_{\Omega} (-w) = \max_{\partial\Omega} (-w) = 0$. But since $\max (-w) = \min w$ we have $w\equiv 0$.

Comment: Does it stand that $\max_{\partial{\Omega}}w=0$ because $w=0$ on $\partial{\Omega}$ ??

Comment: Yes. And for the same reason you have $\max_{\partial\Omega} (-w)=0$.

Comment: I see... I have also an other question... Does it stand that $$\Delta (-w)=-\Delta w$$ ??

Comment: Yes, because derivatives are linear.

Comment: Ok.Thank you!!We apply the same methodology also at the following problem:$$u_t(x, t)-\Delta u(x, t)=f(x, t), x \in \Omega,t>0\\ u(x, t)=h(x, t), x\in \partial{\Omega}, t>0 \\ u(x, 0)=g(x), x \in \Omega$$ right?? We suppose that $u_1, u_2$  are two different solutions of the problem, so $w=u_1-u_2$ solves the following two problems:$$w_t(x,t)-\Delta w(x,t), x \in \partial{\Omega}, t>0\\ 
w(x, t)=0, x \in \partial{\Omega}, t>0\\ 
w(x, 0)=0, x \in \Omega$$ and $$-w_t(x,t)-\Delta (-w(x,t)), x \in \partial{\Omega}, t>0\\ 
-w(x, t)=0, x \in \partial{\Omega}, t>0\\ 
-w(x, 0)=0, x \in \Omega$$

Comment: Since $w_t-\Delta w \leq 0$ from the maximum principle for $w$ we have that $$\max_{x \in \Omega, t \in [0, T]}w(x, t)=\max_{(\Omega \times \{0\})\cup (\partial{\Omega} \times [0, T])}w(x, t)=0$$  Since $-w_t-\Delta (-w) \leq 0$ from the maximum principle for $-w$ we have that $$\max_{x \in \Omega, t \in [0, T]}(-w(x, t))=\max_{(\Omega \times \{0\})\cup (\partial{\Omega} \times [0, T])}(-w(x, t))=0$$ Since $\max (-w)=\min (w)$ we have that $w \equiv 0$. So, $u_1=u_2$. Is this correct??